# Need to write one SQL query in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have one table name `employees` where I have `ID` and `hire_date` column. So, I need to write query which will give output like below:

when `hire_date is null` for `ID=101` then it will give `hire_date` of `ID=110`. Vice versa like when `hire_date is null` for `id=110` then it will give `hire date` of `ID=101`

Comment: What if `hire_date IS NULL` for both `ID=101` **and** `ID=110`?

Comment: then it will be any default date

Comment: What is the default date then?

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation in analytic functions to avoid a self-join:

```sql
SELECT e.*,
       CASE
       WHEN hire_date IS NULL AND id = 101
       THEN COALESCE(
              MIN(CASE id WHEN 110 THEN hire_date END) OVER (),
              DATE '1900-01-01' -- Default if both NULL
            )
       WHEN hire_date IS NULL AND id = 110
       THEN COALESCE(
              MIN(CASE id WHEN 101 THEN hire_date END) OVER (),
              DATE '1900-01-01' -- Default if both NULL
            )
       ELSE hire_date -- value for other rows.
       END AS value
FROM   employees e;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE employees (id, name, hire_date) AS
SELECT 101, 'Alice', DATE '1970-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 110, 'Beryl', NULL              FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 111, 'Carol', DATE '1980-01-01' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | NAME | HIRE_DATE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Alice | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 110 | Beryl | *null* | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 111 | Carol | 1980-01-01 00:00:00 | 1980-01-01 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/L4icpe6r)

Comment: I would personally prefer subselect because of better readability but I am upvoting this answer since it is beautiful case of unusual usage of analytic functions.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    hire_date,
    CASE
        WHEN hire_date IS NULL AND id = 101 THEN
            ( SELECT hire_date FROM employees WHERE id = 110 )
        WHEN hire_date IS NULL AND id = 110 THEN
            ( SELECT hire_date FROM employees WHERE id = 101 )
        ELSE
            NULL
    END AS hire_date2
FROM
    employees
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way...

```sql
-- sample data
WITH
    emps AS
        (
            SELECT 101 "ID", 'John' "NAME", To_Date('01.08.2000', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "HIRE_DATE" FROM DUAL Union All
            SELECT 110 "ID", 'Jane' "NAME", Null "HIRE_DATE" FROM DUAL Union All
            SELECT 120 "ID", 'Mark' "NAME", To_Date('01.10.2000', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "HIRE_DATE" FROM DUAL
        )
-- main SQL
SELECT
    ID, NAME, HIRE_DATE,
    CASE WHEN ID = 101 THEN Nvl(HIRE_DATE, ( SELECT hire_date FROM emps WHERE id = 110 )    )
         WHEN ID = 110 THEN Nvl(HIRE_DATE, ( SELECT hire_date FROM emps WHERE id = 101 )    )
    ELSE
        HIRE_DATE
    END "ALTERNATIVE_HIRE_DATE"
FROM
    emps
```

R e s u l t :

| ID | NAME | HIRE_DATE | ALTERNATIVE_HIRE_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | John | 01-AUG-00 | 01-AUG-00 |
| 110 | Jane |  | 01-AUG-00 |
| 120 | Mark | 01-OCT-00 | 01-OCT-00 |

And if there is a possibility of having null values in both hiredates (ids 101 and 110) then you can do it with nested Nvl() functions.

```sql
-- sample data (2)
WITH
    emps AS
        (
            SELECT 101 "ID", 'John' "NAME", Null "HIRE_DATE" FROM DUAL Union All
            SELECT 110 "ID", 'Jane' "NAME", Null "HIRE_DATE" FROM DUAL Union All
            SELECT 120 "ID", 'Mark' "NAME", To_Date('01.10.2000', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "HIRE_DATE" FROM DUAL
        )
-- main SQL
SELECT
    ID, NAME, HIRE_DATE,
    CASE WHEN ID = 101 THEN Nvl(Nvl(HIRE_DATE, ( SELECT hire_date FROM emps WHERE id = 110 )    ), To_Date('01.01.2000', 'dd.mm.yyyy'))
         WHEN ID = 110 THEN Nvl(Nvl(HIRE_DATE, ( SELECT hire_date FROM emps WHERE id = 101 )    ), To_Date('01.01.2000', 'dd.mm.yyyy'))
    ELSE
        HIRE_DATE
    END "ALTERNATIVE_HIRE_DATE"
FROM
    emps
```

R e s u l t :

| ID | NAME | HIRE_DATE | ALTERNATIVE_HIRE_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | John |  | 01-JAN-00 |
| 110 | Jane |  | 01-JAN-00 |
| 120 | Mark | 01-OCT-00 | 01-OCT-00 |